# ¿Cómo sería la sintaxis de PDO::FETCH_ASSOC en este código?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quiero obtener los datos de un usuario de una base de datos con FETCH_ASSOC.

**personajes.php:**

```html
<?php
include '../lib/con-pdo.php';
$u = $_COOKIE['usr'];
$ce = $_COOKIE['pwd'];
$accsql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = '$u' or Email = '$u' and Contra = '$ce'");
$stmtacc=$db->prepare($accsql);
$stmtacc->execute();
// compruebo si los datos son correctos.
if($stmtacc->fetchColumn()==1)
{
  // bucle para intentar obtener los datos que no me funciona
 while($row = $stmtacc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  $nick = $row['Nick'];
  $password = $row['Contra'];
  $email = $row['Email'];
  echo $password;
   }
}
?>
```

El código no lanza ningún error, simplemente nada. Sé que es una pregunta "duplicada", pero ya intenté con propuestas echas en otras preguntas y no me han servido.

Comment: Ese código no amerita el uso de esto `while($row = $stmtacc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` porque **trae una sola fila/columna** y ya la obtienes aquí: `$stmtacc->fetchColumn()` ... Lo que sí presenta es un grave problema de seguridad, que salta a la vista teniendo justo al lado un `prepare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta que ejecuta tu código es un `COUNT(*)`, por tanto devolverá **una sola fila**, y ninguna otra columna que la indicada.

Si quieres seleccionar otros datos, tienes que ponerlos en el `SELECT`.

```
<?php
    include '../lib/con-pdo.php';
    $u = $_COOKIE['usr'];
    $ce = $_COOKIE['pwd'];
    $accsql="SELECT Nick, Contra, Email FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = :Nick or Email = :Email and Contra = :Contra";
    $stmtacc=$db->prepare($accsql);
    $arrParams=array(":Nick"=>$u, ":Email"=>$u, ":Contra"=>$ce);

    // compruebo si los datos son correctos.
    if( $stmtacc && $stmtacc->execute($arrParams) )
    {
      // bucle para intentar obtener los datos que no me funciona
        while($row = $stmtacc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $nick = $row['Nick'];
            $password = $row['Contra'];
            $email = $row['Email'];
            echo $password;
       }
    }else{

        echo "Error en la consulta: ".$stmtacc->errorInfo()[2];     
    }
?>
```

Si al mismo tiempo quieres verificar primero si hay datos, puedes lanzar primero un `COUNT` y a partir del resultado lanzar la otra consulta. O puedes llenar un array dentro del `while` y luego verificar si está o no vacío.

En el código he corregido la vulnerabilidad de inyección SQL.

Comment: El código me sirvió. Pero podrías, por favor, explicarme a qué se debe el doble punto y coma este: $arrParams=array(":Nick"=>$u, ":Email"=>$u, ":Contra"=>$ce);
    **;**

Comment: @Morderisk ese fue un error mío al escribir, va un solo punto y coma. Ahora corrijo.